# Completing a stream from an actor ref?

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

I have a `Source[T, ActorRef[T]]` that was created via calling `ActorSource.actorRef[T]` as per https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/operators/ActorSource/actorRef.html. When I send the type matched by the completion matcher, the stream does not end as expected. Is there some other action I need to take to successfully complete the stream?

Here is code:

```scala
sealed trait ActorProtocol
case class Response(r: HttpResponse) extends ActorProtocol
object Complete extends ActorProtocol

// ... in a function that creates the stream
val (actor, httpSource) = ActorSource.actorRef[ActorProtocol](
      completionMatcher = { case Complete => println("Complete message sent!")},
      failureMatcher = PartialFunction.empty,
      bufferSize = 100,
      OverflowStrategy.dropNew
    ).preMaterialize()

// ... a while later, want to end the stream
actor ! Complete

// in console, see "Complete message sent!"
```

Since as the console showed, the message was received by the actor materialized by the stream, I'd expect the stream to complete, except it does not.

Here is some more code:

```scala
// a class to make completing the stream more ergonomic
sealed abstract class Completable[T](ref: ActorRef[T], completeMessage: T) with Cancellable {
   def complete = 
      cancel
      ref ! completeMessage
}

// in companion object
def fromCancellable[T](cancellable)(actor: ActorRef[T], completeMessage: T) = new Completable(actor, completeMessage) { override def cancel = cancellable.cancel }

// body of function that creates the stream - yields Source[HttpResponse, Completable]
val (actor, httpSource) = ActorSource.actorRef[ActorProtocol](
      completionMatcher = { case Complete => println("Complete message sent!")},
      failureMatcher = PartialFunction.empty,
      bufferSize = 100,
      OverflowStrategy.dropNew
    ).preMaterialize()

val runnable = new Runnable {
      override def run(): Unit = httpClient.makeRequest(request) onComplete {
        case Failure(exception) => throw exception
        case Success(res) => 
          actor ! Response(res)
      }
    }
val completable = fromCancellable(akkaScheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(Duration.Zero, dur)(runnable))
httpSource
  .via(Flow.fromFunction[ActorProtocol, HttpResponse] { p => p match {
    case Response(r) => r
  }})
  .mapMaterializedValue(_ => completable)

// how it gets called
val (completable, stream) = codeToCreateStream

// ... some time later
completable.complete
// see complete message printed, expect stream to complete, but it does not :(
```

EDIT: Here is the full code that creates the stream in question: `Scheduler` is just a wrapper against a scheduler so it returns a cancellable, from which we create a completable that cancels the scheduled task and send the `Complete` message to the actor ref (intended as sort of a completion hook for the stream)

```scala
override def get(request: HttpRequest, cadence: Cadence, failureStrat: FailureStrategy): Source[HttpResponse, Completable] = {
    val (actor, httpSource) = ActorSource.actorRef[ActorProtocol](
      completionMatcher = { case Complete => },
      failureMatcher = { case Failed => new RuntimeException("failure")},
      bufferSize = 100,
      OverflowStrategy.fail
    ).preMaterialize()
    val runnable = new Runnable {
      override def run(): Unit = httpClient.makeRequest(request) onComplete {
        case Failure(exception) => 
          println(exception.getMessage())
          actor ! Failed
        case Success(res) => 
          actor ! Response(res)
      }
    }
    val c = scheduler.schedule(cadence)(runnable)
    val f = Flow.fromFunction[ActorProtocol, HttpResponse] { p => 
      p match {
        case Response(r) => r
        case Complete => println("Received Complete"); throw new RuntimeException("Muh")
      }
    }
    httpSource.via(f).mapMaterializedValue(_ => Completable.fromCancelable(c)(actor, Complete))
  }
```

The code where I run this stream looks like

```scala
val (completable, stream) = get(request, cadence, failure).preMaterialize()
stream
  .runForeach(println).onComplete {
    case Success(value) => 
      println("Done!")
      sys.terminate()
    case Failure(exception) => println(exception.getMessage())
  }
  Thread.sleep(7000)
  completable.complete
```

Answer (score 1):

The stream will complete when all stages in the stream complete.

`ActorSource.actorRef` will complete after receiving a message matching the `completionMatcher` and after signalling all buffered elements to the next stage in the stream.  Many of the other standard stream stages will complete when the upstream completes, but not all will (and for custom stages, that depends on the implementation: one can define a stream stage that never completes); for example the fan-in operators often won't complete until *all* their upstreams complete (though for some, there's an `eagerComplete` flag which will complete if any upstream completes).

`codeToCreateStream` isn't provided, but I'd suggest checking the docs for the stages in the stream you're creating for when they complete.

Comment: Thanks - `codeToCreateStream` is just the big chunk after `// body of function that creates the stream - yields Source[HttpResponse, Completable]
`
Since I just chain flows together downstream, I can't think of what didn't complete, but I'll keep looking.

Comment: I added more code if that helps thank you :)

Comment: So idk if this makes _any_ sense, but this worked when I replaced `via(f)` with `.map { case Response(r) => r }`. I need to do more investigation to make sure that is right because it seems so counterintuitive, and I think if it is right it would be a bug no?

Comment: Yeah, `.via(Flow.fromFunction(fun))` should be exactly equivalent to `.map(fun)`.  It's probably worth a ticket against Akka once you have a minimal reproducer.